# How to detect if Chrome/Safari/Firefox prevented autoplay for video?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, safari, video.js

### Background

Since Chrome version 66, videos that should autoplay on my site may be prevented from playing if the user hasn't been on my site before.

```html
<video src="..." autoplay></video>
```

### Question

How do I detect if the video autoplay was disabled? And what can I do about it?

Comment: Chrome seems to prevent autoplay sometimes even if you've visited the site 100 times, but only sometimes. The inconsistency makes testing extemely hard, and I don't think VideoJS works with the promise framework detailed in the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, the Media Engagement Index may seem like black magic, but it is clearly stated in https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_278v_plodvgtXSgnEJ0yjZJLg14Ogf-ekAFNymAJoU/edit# how it is measured. VideoJS does support returning a promise when it is available in the browser. https://docs.videojs.com/player.js.html#line2172

Comment: Testing Tip for Safari on iOS: Turn on low battery mode and it will block auto-play. This is the easiest way to test. Not sure what Android does.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## The `autoplay` attribute

According to web standard specifications, the autoplay attribute should only be **a hint** for what the browser should to with the media element. Neither of [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/) of [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) web specifications mentions anything about when to prevent autoplay for media, which means that each browser probably have different implementations.

## Autoplay policies

Autoplay policies implemented by each browser now govern whether video should be allowed to autoplay.

- Chrome uses something they call Media
  Engagement Index and you can read more about that [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_278v_plodvgtXSgnEJ0yjZJLg14Ogf-ekAFNymAJoU/edit#) and their autoplay policy [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).
- Safari developers made a [post on webkit.org](https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/)
  regarding this.
- Firefox seems to put it in the hands of the user to choose if it's allowed or not ([link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay)).

## Best practices

### Detecting if autoplay is disabled

Instead of using `autoplay` on your element, you can use the `play()` method on the `video` and `audio` element to start playing your media. The `play()` method returns a promise in modern browsers (all according to the spec). If the promise rejects, it can indicate that autoplay is disabled in the current browser on your site.

[can-autoplay](https://github.com/video-dev/can-autoplay) is a library solely for detecting autoplay features for both video and audio elements.

### When autoplay is disabled

The good thing is that when you know that autoplay is disabled you can, in some browsers, then mute the video and try the `play()` method again, while showing something in the UI that says that the video is playing while muted.

```js
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var promise = video.play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
  promise.then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started!
  }).catch(error => {
    // Autoplay not allowed!
    // Mute video and try to play again
    video.muted = true;
    video.play();

    // Show something in the UI that the video is muted
  });
}
```

```html
<video src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" controls></video>
```

Comment: @sea-kg, what exactly isn't working? Could be that your version of Safari does not support video.play() returning a Promise.

Comment: Safari version is Version 12.0.3 (14606.4.5). Detect not working correctly
In my case best solution was handle errors NotAllowedError for Chrome And Firefox and "AbortError" only for Safari

Comment: is there any way to do this without attempting to play the audio first?

Comment: Not sure, but if the audio does play, you can always pause it immediately after it successfully plays.

Answer (score 2):

For me best solution was:

```
function _callback_onAutoplayBlocked() {
    // do something, for example "show big play button"
}

function isSafari() {
    var chr = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") > -1;
    var sfri = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("safari") > -1;
    return !chr && sfri;
}

function _checkAutoPlay(p) {
    var s = window['Promise'] ? window['Promise'].toString() : '';

    if (s.indexOf('function Promise()') !== -1 || s.indexOf('function ZoneAwarePromise()') !== -1) {
        p.catch(function(error) {
            console.error("_checkAutoPlay, error:", error)
            if(error.name == "NotAllowedError") { // For Chrome/Firefox
                console.error("_checkAutoPlay: error.name:", "NotAllowedError")
                _callback_onAutoplayBlocked();
            } else if (error.name == "AbortError" && isSafari()) {  // Only for Safari
                console.error("_checkAutoPlay: AbortError (Safari)")
                _callback_onAutoplayBlocked();
            } else {
                console.error("_checkAutoPlay: happened something else ", error);
                // throw error; // happened something else
            }
        }).then(function(){
            console.log("_checkAutoPlay: then");
            // Auto-play started
        });
    } else {
        console.error("_checkAutoplay: promise could not work in your browser ", p);
    }
}

var video1 = document.getElementById('video1');
_checkAutoPlay(video1.play());
```