# Can we detect if autoplay sound is blocked on Firefox 66 and more?

Tags: javascript, firefox, permissions, autoplay

I'm trying to figure out a way to see if in firefox 66 it autoplay is enabled. There is a new policy where videos will not be played automatically. I'm trying to find a way to code this.

Any thoughts or ideas? I've tried searching for more information relating to firefox 66 but seem to have no success

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  HTMLMediaElement.autoplay = true | false;
  var autoplay = HTMLMediaElement.autoplay;

  if (BrowserDetect.browser === "Firefox" && autoplay == false) {

    $('#firefox-autoplay-message').slideDown();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#firefox-autoplay-message').slideUp();
    }, 900000);

  }
});
```

This has no results or detection

Comment: You probably find what you are looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939436/how-to-detect-if-chrome-safari-firefox-prevented-autoplay-for-video

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken but I think this only applies to Safari and Chrome and not to Firefox 66 +?