# navigator.getAutoplayPolicy does not work in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, autoplay, soundmanager2

I test an app on Google Chrome **Version 120.0.6099.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)**. I am trying to write a function to check if autoplay is allowed or not. I tried:

```
navigator.getAutoplayPolicy("mediaelement");
```

It works fine with FireFox 120.0.1 (64-bit). but in Chrome it returns error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: navigator.getAutoplayPolicy is not a function
```

I could not able to find any work around for Google Chrome. Is there such work around?

Answer (score 0):

[getAutoplayPolicy](https://caniuse.com/?search=getAutoplayPolicy) is not supported by Chrome 120 yet.

To check autoplay is disabled look at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939436/how-to-detect-if-chrome-safari-firefox-prevented-autoplay-for-video)